# Percent change for multiple events in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Random points on a picture of a coral reef were recorded. Using dplyr, I found the percent cover of a species (ID) by taking the number of times a point had a specific species divided by the total number of points. Bellow is an excerpt of this data.

```
Event                ID    Percent
    2   Bryozoan         0.2222222
    2   Chlorophyta      0.2222222
    3   Chlorophyta      0.2222222
    1   Coralline Algae  1.3333333
    2   Coralline Algae  2
    3   Coralline Algae  1.7777778
    4   Coralline Algae  7.1111111
    2   Macroalgae       1.1111111
```

I am trying to find the percent change between 4 events. So in my example for coralline algae the percent change from event 1 to 2 where it increased from 1.333% to 2%,would be

(2/1.33) * 100% = 150,

150-100 = 50%, So a 50% increase.

I would then need to do the percent change from each event 1 to 3, 1 to 4, 2 to 3 and so on.

I have seen similar problems use the lag() function but I do not know how to use this in my case as a species (ID) may not be found in every event. How should I go about this in R? Would it be easier to put my data in wide format? (will update if so)

Comment: " event 1 to 3, 1 to 4, 2 to 3 " suggests that you want all pair combinations of event pairs? how do you want this to be stored? This is in contrast to only wanting consecutive events 1-2, 2-3, 3-4, which excludes (1-3, 2-4 etc)

Comment: Yes all pair combinations, sorry I couldn't think of the phrase.

Comment: Are you sure this dataset - which does not contain four events for each ID- is the correct one? You might be better off posting an example of your raw data, rather than asking for percentage increase of percentages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the table onto itself to produce the desired combinations of events. I filter to make sure that the second event number is larger than the first (if they are the same then the change is zero, if the second is smaller then it's just the negative of a different pair.) Note that the original first and last rows don't appear here because there are no other events to compare them to.

```r
library(tidyverse)
tbl <- read_table2(
"Event  ID  Percent
2   Bryozoan    0.2222222
2   Chlorophyta 0.2222222
3   Chlorophyta 0.2222222
1   CorallineAlgae 1.3333333
2   CorallineAlgae 2
3   CorallineAlgae 1.7777778
4   CorallineAlgae 7.1111111
2   Macroalgae  1.1111111"
)
tbl %>%
  arrange(ID, Event) %>%
  left_join(tbl, by = c("ID")) %>%
  filter(Event.y > Event.x) %>%
  mutate(Percent.change = (Percent.y / Percent.x) - 1) %>%
  select(ID, Event.x, Event.y, Percent.x, Percent.y, Percent.change)
#> # A tibble: 7 x 6
#>   ID             Event.x Event.y Percent.x Percent.y Percent.change
#>   <chr>            <int>   <int>     <dbl>     <dbl>          <dbl>
#> 1 Chlorophyta          2       3     0.222     0.222          0    
#> 2 CorallineAlgae       1       2     1.33      2              0.500
#> 3 CorallineAlgae       1       3     1.33      1.78           0.333
#> 4 CorallineAlgae       1       4     1.33      7.11           4.33 
#> 5 CorallineAlgae       2       3     2         1.78          -0.111
#> 6 CorallineAlgae       2       4     2         7.11           2.56 
#> 7 CorallineAlgae       3       4     1.78      7.11           3.00
```

Created on 2018-10-16 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: As is I get this error message "In Ops.factor(Event.y, Event.x) : ‘>’ not meaningful for factors". When I remove the filter it then works. Recommendations for making the filter work?

Comment: The error message says "not meaningful for factors", which suggests that you have read in `Event` as a factor. Make the event values integers instead of factors?

Comment: Converted Events to integer and same error message, but the main goal is still achieved. Thank you.

Comment: If you just add a conversion into the pipe then when you join it onto itself the second copy will still be a factor